# Publishing to Azure - MDF File is not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

I am developing a project with Visual Studio 2015 and trying to publish it to Azure. While publishing, it throws an error stating that **.mdf** file under `app_data` directory is not found.

I deleted it because I'm using Azure's DB.

Why should I keep the mdf file in the `App_data` folder?

Comment: If you're using an azure database, there is no reason to keep the .mdf in the App_data folder.  Is there a reference in the project or publish profile to the non-existing file?

Comment: What bot framework are using? What database are you using? The .mdf file should not be accessible if you are using Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have created a mdf file inside the App_Data folder. The file is deleted from file explorer, but the file record haven't been removed from the project file. To check it, you could open your project file using notepad.

[image]

After opened the project file. You could search 'App_Data' to check whether there are content records like following. If yes, you just need to remove these records and save the project file.

```
<Content Include="App_Data\Database1.mdf" />
<Content Include="App_Data\Database1_log.ldf">
  <DependentUpon>Database1.mdf</DependentUpon>
</Content>
```

Comment: After I deleted the mdf file from the App_data folder in Solution Explorer it starts working.

Comment: 'deleted the mdf file from the App_data folder in Solution Explorer ' just worked for me in VS 2022!